# Linear algebra: from the inner product to the dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $W$ be a $n$-dimensional vector space. What do we mean when we say that a linear transformation $f:W\to \mathbb{R}^n$ carries the inner product on $W$ to the dot product on $\mathbb{R}^n$? Is there such a linear transformation?
Can you give me an example?

Comment: It preserves inner products. Any orthogonal transformation (transformation whose matrix is orthogonal) will do this, or isometry

Comment: How to prove this is true for all orthogonal transformations?

Comment: @user249031: Your question currently isn't well-posed. In order to speak of "_the_ inner product on $W$" you have to equip $W$ with an inner product; a real vector space does not come with a natural inner product. Is that your situation, i.e., you have an $n$-dimensional real vector space $W$ equipped with an inner product? Or are you asking: Given a linear isomorphism $f$, how can we define an inner product on $W$ so that $f$ carries the inner product on $W$ to the Euclidean inner product?

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of this is the following. Imagine you have two vectors $v,w \in W$ and you want to compute their inner product. Then a map $f$ that carries the inner product on $W$ to the dot product on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ allows you to compute the inner product of $v$ and $w$ as the dot product of the vectors $f(v) , f(w) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.  The tipical example is the map $f:W \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ which assigns to a vector $v$ its column of coordinates $f(v)$ $$ f(v) := \left( \begin{array}{c}
v_1 \\
v_2 \\
\vdots \\
v_n
 \end{array} \right) $$ w.r.t. an orthogonal basis $B=(b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_n)$ of $W$.  It is easy to show that orthogonal basis do exists. Indeed, take a unit vector $b_1$, then take a unit vector $b_2$ in the orthogonal complement of $b_1$, then take a third one in the orthogonal complement of the first two, and so on.

Comment: Does any orthogonal transformation allow this?

Comment: By an orthogonal transformation I understand a map $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ that carries the inner product to the inner product i.e. for all $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^n$  $f(v) \cdot f(w) = v \cdot w$ . So if your $W$ is already $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ then a map which carries the inner product into the dot product is indeed an orthogonal transformation (by the very definition!)